# Displaying Panel(s) based on Radio Button Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I currently have the following code on my page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="GroupButtons" CellSpacing="5" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" selected="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="6" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="7" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Panel ID="GroupPanel" runat="server">
    <b>How can we improve our service?</b><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="GroupTextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

This code is also repeated in different sections (IndividualButtons/IndividualPanel, EducationButtons/EducationPanel, etc.)

I am attempting to figure out an elegant solution to do the following:

- When the selected value of a radio button list is 0 or 5-7, hide the associated panel.
- When the selected value is 1-4, show the associated panel.
- Have this code work for all of the sections, in order to avoid bloat (if possible).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: the following code gets my GroupPanel panel to hide and show every time the GroupButtons selection changes. But again, I need it to show for 1-4, and hide for 0 and 5-7.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = '<%= GroupButtons.ClientId %>_0';
       $(function() {
        var i = 0

        $('#<%= GroupButtons.ClientId %> :radio').click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('id') != id) {
                $('#<%= GroupPanel.ClientId%>').toggle();
                id = $(this).attr('id');
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using asp.net:
This is code that you will use in the selectedIndexChanged event:

You could create a list(values for which you want to display the panel) and check if the selected value is present in that list.

```
List<string> displayList = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3","4" };
GroupPanel.Visible = displayList.Contains(GroupButtons.SelectedValue) ? true : false;
```

As this is repeated in different sections, you can create the list in the business object with a get property and use it in the code behind to check the value.

Since you have updated the question now and are looking for something on the client side, this may help:

**Fiddle :**http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/2174/

This how your code will look:

```
 <div class="toggleDisplay">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="GroupButtons" CellSpacing="5" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="true" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Panel ID="GroupPanel" runat="server">
                <b>How can we improve our service?</b><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="GroupTextBox" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>

        <div class="toggleDisplay">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="EducationButtons" CellSpacing="5" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="true" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Panel ID="EducationPanel" runat="server">
                <b>How can we improve our service?</b><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
```

Description: Put the buttons and the panel in a div with a class of toggleDisplay.
Important point here is the panel id should end with the word "Panel" as we will be using this in the jquery.

This is what will go in the script tag:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").hide();
        $(".toggleDisplay").change(function () {
            var groupName = $(this).find(":radio").attr('name');
            var ans = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:radio:checked').val();
            var displaylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
            if (displaylist.indexOf(ans) > -1) {
                $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").show();
            } else {
                $(this).find("[id$='Panel']").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

So anything with a class of toggleDisplay will fire this script.

Comment: That did the trick nicely, although your script between here & Fiddle were different (and I needed the Fiddle version). Thank you!